# Creating a jquery function for onkeypress

Tags: jquery

I have a function that is triggered by an onkeypress event. It is coded like this

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

I want to create another function for a different field that prevents anything except upper and lower case chars, hyphens, and spaces being entered.

I tested this in jsfiddle and it works on a simple input field

```
$('input').on('keypress', function (e) {
  if (/^[a-zA-Z\-/\ /b]+$/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
    return;
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

But I can't figure out how to make that into a function for an onkeypress event.

Based on the code for the "isNumberKey" function, I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
function isLetterKey(evt){
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (/^[a-zA-Z\-/\ /b]+$/.test(String.fromCharCode))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong in creating this function?

Comment: Put everything you have in your anonymous callback function into the body of `function isLetterKey(e) {}`

Comment: What you have in your second example *is* a function for an onkeypress event. If you want it to be a _named_ function, move it and give it a name, then refer to it in the event binding.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't passing your `charCode` into `String.fromCharCode()`, so you were testing an empty string

Also, `.test()` returns `true` or `false`, so you don't need the if / else

```js
$('input').on('keypress', function (e) {
  let char = e.which || e.keyCode;
  
  return /^[a-zA-Z\-/\ /b]+$/.test(String.fromCharCode(char));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```